# XSLT: Conditional text exclusion/replacement

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been tasked with doing some xslt for the first time as a POC and stumbling through a solution. The issue I am 
having is being able to replace the contents of a node with what is returned by my function when a match occurs. At the 
moment I am having issues putting it together such that the original text inside the run tag does not come through as well
as this should be replaced with the content defined by my handle-links function when the test is TRUE. michael.hor257k gave 
some good advice around my problem in a previous post which is now closed but I am still puzzled as to the correct syntax
I need to apply to achieve the desired outcome. If someone could give me a hand as to the correct modifications to make that would be 
great and much appreciated.

Given the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <par def='15'>
        <run>
            <font size='8pt' name='Verdana' pitch='variable' truetype='true'
 familyid='20' color='navy'/>[&lt;a href="www.google.com.au" target="_new"&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;]
        </run>
    </par>
</catalog>
```

And applying the correct XSLT (which I need assistance with)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My Transform</h2>  
                <xsl:apply-templates/>  
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="run">
        <font name='Verdana' size='14pt'>
            <xsl:call-template name="handle-links">
                <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </font>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="handle-links">

        <xsl:param name="txt"/>

        <xsl:if
            test="contains($txt,'[&lt;a')">

            <xsl:variable name="quotes">"</xsl:variable>    

            <!-- Get URL -->
            <xsl:variable name="urlVar" select='substring-before(substring-after($txt, $quotes), $quotes)'/> 

            <!-- Get Link Name -->
            <xsl:variable name="linkName" select='substring-before(substring-after($txt, "&gt;"), "&lt;")'/> 

            <a href="{$urlVar}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$linkName"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to achieve something like below IF AND ONLY IF the test test="contains($txt,'[<a')"> is true.

```
<font name='Verdana' size='14pt'>
    <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
</font>
```

If the test `test="contains($txt,'[&lt;a')">` is FALSE, then I just want the `<font name = 'Verdana' size='14pt'> </font>` tags to surround the `text()` contents of the run element.

Cheers,

Comment: The above XSLT does actually output what you want in the case `contains($txt,'[<a')` is true. Is it only the "false" case you need help with? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tim, yes I need it to work for the false condition as well. I've been playing with different permutations in the XSLT Tryit Editor v1.2 and couldn't get the above code to generate the output so assumed there was an issue with it. If there is a better Editor to use for experimenting/debugging please let me know as it would help with future work on this project. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `xsl:choose` instead of `xsl:if`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My Transform</h2>  
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="run">
    <font name='Verdana' size='14pt'>
      <xsl:call-template name="handle-links">
        <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </font>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="handle-links">
    <xsl:param name="txt"/>
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains($txt,'[&lt;a')">
        <xsl:variable name="quotes">"</xsl:variable>  
          <!-- Get URL -->
        <xsl:variable name="urlVar" select='substring-before(substring-after($txt, $quotes), $quotes)'/> 
          <!-- Get Link Name -->
        <xsl:variable name="linkName" select='substring-before(substring-after($txt, "&gt;"), "&lt;")'/> 

        <a href="{$urlVar}">
          <xsl:value-of select="$linkName"/>
        </a>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$txt" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another approach would be to have a template matching the text node, rather than a named template, and have the condition in the template match. Try this also

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My Transform</h2>  
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="run">
    <font name='Verdana' size='14pt'>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />
    </font>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="run/text()[contains(.,'[&lt;a')]">
    <xsl:variable name="quotes">"</xsl:variable>  
      <!-- Get URL -->
    <xsl:variable name="urlVar" select='substring-before(substring-after(., $quotes), $quotes)'/> 
      <!-- Get Link Name -->
    <xsl:variable name="linkName" select='substring-before(substring-after(., "&gt;"), "&lt;")'/> 

    <a href="{$urlVar}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$linkName"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the case where the text doesn't contain a link, XSLT's built-in templates will just output the text normally.

See this in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUn (This website is an extremely useful for experimenting and debugging. It also supports XSLT 3.0, which if you could use would allow you to use the [parse-xml](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-parse-xml) command, to potentially make creating the link easier).

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks Tim C. I've just started having a play with .NET XSLT Fiddle and it's great. It's good seeing the various approaches that can be taken so thanks for sharing.